# How to clone this WordPress Plugin ( advanced xml reader )

Tags: xml, wordpress, plugins, feed, cloning

After a bit of research I've found an easy way to display the XML feed in WordPress.

The only problem with this plugin (advanced xml reader) is that it supports just one feed. I need 100!!

The author dont have time to update the plugin and adviced to clone it. Easier said than done..I have changed all what I could think of changing to no avail. It just shows as active but no additional entries appear in WP settings menu.

Now I know that there is probably better way of displaying those feeds but it's dark magic for me.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-xml-reader/

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import. Hope, it's what are you looking for.